# Seperating Json objects based on keyvalue

Tags: json, powershell

currently i am working on fetching Azure ad application expiry status on that i have pulled around 1700 ad applications and i have added one key pair(status) to the json object  based on the secret expiry date

```
1) valid 2) Expired 3) expiring soon
```

so i have extracted all applications to a json file now i need to split single file into 3 files based on status as mentioned below

```
[
    {
        "DisplayName": "Reporter-dev",
        "ObjectId": null,
        "ApplicationId": {
            "value": "62838283828288282828828288282828",
            "Guid": "62838283828288282828828288282828"
        },
        "KeyId": "62838283828288282828828288282828",
        "Type": "Password",
        "StartDate": {
            "value": "/Date(1590537256000)/",
            "DateTime": "27 May 2020 05:24:16"
        },
        "EndDate": {
            "value": "/Date(1653609256000)/",
            "DateTime": "27 May 2022 05:24:16"
        },
        "Ownername": "shetty@gmail.com",
        "Status": "Valid"
    },
    {
        "DisplayName": "azure-cli-2018",
        "ObjectId": null,
        "ApplicationId": {
            "value": "52388282828828288273673282932739223",
            "Guid": "52388282828828288273673282932739223"
        },
        "KeyId": "52388282828828288273673282932739223",
        "Type": "Password",
        "StartDate": {
            "value": "/Date(1568849784000)/",
            "DateTime": "19 September 2019 05:06:24"
        },
        "EndDate": {
            "value": "/Date(1600472184000)/",
            "DateTime": "19 September 2020 05:06:24"
        },
        "Ownername": "joseph@gmail.com",
        "Status": "Expired"
    },
    {
        "DisplayName": "azure-cli-2019",
        "ObjectId": null,
        "ApplicationId": {
            "value": "26382882828828282882828282828",
            "Guid": "26382882828828282882828282828"
        },
        "KeyId": "26382882828828282882828282828",
        "Type": "Password",
        "StartDate": {
            "value": "/Date(1576143476000)/",
            "DateTime": "12 December 2019 15:07:56"
        },
        "EndDate": {
            "value": "/Date(1607765876000)/",
            "DateTime": "12 December 2020 15:07:56"
        },
        "Ownername": "zzzzzzzzz@gmail.com",
        "Status": "About to Expire"
    }
]
```

Comment: What did you try and how did that fail or differ from what you expected? Please update your original question to include the code you've tried and need help with.

Comment: @notjustme Thanks for the reply, firstly i am not a coding expert i tried to do with my basic powershell and that doesn't  help me to to separate the files, so I have posted here for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below will split out the JSON based on the status and convert the data back to JSON. Change `$JSONPath, $ValidPath, $ExpiredPath, $ExpiredSoonPath` to the paths you require, the ones currently populated are what I have used for testing.

The contents of $JSONPath must have valid JSON to be able to work, whilst this is probably not the most efficient nor elegant it should do what you need.

```
$JSONPath = "C:\PS\JT\JSON.txt"

$JSONObj = Get-Content $JSONPath | ConvertFrom-Json

$ValidPath = "C:\PS\JT\Valid.txt"
$ExpiredPath = "C:\PS\JT\Expired.txt"
$ExpireSoonPath = "C:\PS\JT\ExpireSoon.txt"


$JSONObj | Where {$_.Status -eq "Valid"} | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File $ValidPath
$JSONObj | Where {$_.Status -eq "Expired"} | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File $ExpiredPath
$JSONObj | Where {$_.Status -eq "About to Expire"} | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File $ExpireSoonPath
```

Answer (score 1):

Something very simple like the below example should work in theory but since you won't show your code there's a bunch of guess work here...

```
$collection = $json | ConvertFrom-Json
$valid = @(); $exp = @(); $soon = @(); $unknown = @()

foreach($item in $collection) {
    
    switch ($item.Status)
    {
        'Valid' { $valid += $item }
        'Expired' { $exp += $item }
        'About to Expire' { $soon += $item }
            Default { $unknown += $item}
    }
}

$valid | Out-File .\Valid.txt -Append
$exp | Out-File .\Expired.txt -Append
$soon | Out-File .\AboutToExpire.txt -Append
$unknown | Out-File .\Unknown.txt -Append
```

Or if json is the desired output as in the other example;

```
$valid | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File .\Valid.txt -Append
```

etc, etc

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the other answers, here is another solutions using pipelines.

```
Get-Content -Path .\sample.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json | 
    ForEach-Object { $_ | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File -FilePath "$($_.Status).json" }
```

**Explanation**

- Parse JSON content using [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.1), also making sure we use the `-Raw` switch to return the contents as one string with the newlines preserved. We don't need the contents as an array of strings(default behaviour).
- Pipe to [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7.1) to deserialize the JSON into a [`System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscustomobject?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0).
- Iterate over the objects using `Foreach-Object` and convert the object to a JSON file using [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-7.1) and [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-7.1). Note the default depth for `ConvertTo-Json` is 2, so if your JSON files end up having deeper levels, then you will need to specify a larger depth using the `-Depth` switch.

If its easier understand, you can also use a regular `foreach` loop here:

```
$json = Get-Content -Path .\sample.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json

foreach ($object in $json) {
    $object | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File -FilePath "$($object.Status).json"
}
```